# Solidity how to check if user is already used another contract?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, remix, interfaces

I am trying to figure out how to set up a simple communication between contracts.

For example, we have a contract Passport, in which the user writes his data. After that, through the Election contract, the user votes. The contract Election should check if the user has a passport and only then allow him to vote.

Here is how I am trying to do it:

**Passport contract**

```
contract Passport
{
    struct      Person
    {
        string  name;
        string  surname;
        uint8   age;
        uint256 id;
        bool    registered;
    }

    address payable public              owner;
    mapping(address => Person) public   people;
    uint256                             idCount;

    modifier ownerOnly()
    {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }

    constructor() public payable
    {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function registerID(string memory _name, string memory _surname, uint8 _age) public
    {
        require(!people[msg.sender].registered);

        people[msg.sender].name = _name;
        people[msg.sender].surname = _surname;
        people[msg.sender].age = _age;
        people[msg.sender].id = idCount;

        people[msg.sender].registered = true;

        idCount += 1;
    }

    // I use this function to check is the user have passport
    function isRegistered(address _address) public view returns (bool)
    {
        return people[_address].registered;
    }

    function end() ownerOnly public
    {
        selfdestruct(owner);
    }
}
```

**Election contract**

```
contract Election
{
    struct      Candidate
    {
        string  name;
        uint    voteCount;
    }

    struct      Voter
    {
        bool    authorized;
        bool    voted;
        uint    voteTarget;
    }
    address payable  public             owner;
    string public                       electionName;
    mapping(address => Voter) public    voters;
    Candidate[] public                  candidates;
    uint public                         totalVotes;
    Passport                            pass;

    modifier ownerOnly()
    {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }

    constructor(string memory _electionName) public
    {
        owner = msg.sender;
        electionName = _electionName;
    }

    function addCandidate(string memory _candidateName) ownerOnly public
    {
        candidates.push(Candidate(_candidateName, 0));
    }

    function getNumCandidate() public view returns(uint)
    {
        return candidates.length;
    }

    function authorize(address _person) public
    {
        voters[_person].authorized = true;
    }

    function vote(uint _voteIndex) public
    {
        // Here I register pasport with current user address
        pass = Pasport(msg.sender);

        // Here I check if the user already have pasport
        require(pass.isRegistered(msg.sender));

        require(!voters[msg.sender].voted);
        require(voters[msg.sender].authorized);

        voters[msg.sender].voteTarget = _voteIndex;
        voters[msg.sender].voted = true;

        candidates[_voteIndex].voteCount += 1;
        totalVotes += 1;
    }

    function end() ownerOnly public
    {
        selfdestruct(owner);
    }
}
```

What is the correct way to check if a user is already used another contract? Because mine always gives false. And I can't find the way to do it properly.

Comment: Please post only the part of your code which is relevant to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a high level, your `Election` contract needs knowledge of the ABI and the location of the `Passport` contract. Here's a minimalist setup.

interface:

```
interface PassportInterface {
  // interface can't use `public`, so change to `external`.
  function isRegistered(address _address) external view returns(bool);
}
```

Set up storage for a contract instance within `Election`.

```
contract Election {
  // state var
  PassportInterface passportContract; // type var; as with uint x; or address a;
  // carry on
}
```

Instantiate it. The usual way to get the address is to pass it into the constructor.

```
constructor(string memory _electionName, address passportContractAddress) public ... 
  passportContract = PassportInterface(passportContractAddress);
  // carry on
}
```

Use it.

```
require(passportContract.isRegistered(msg.sender), "You don't have a passport");
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you. With your help, I managed to make it work :) The only thing I fixed was from the public to external in the interface.  function isRegistered(address _address) external view returns(bool);

Comment: Good catch. That's what I get for an ad-hoc answer instead of checking in Remix. Glad it didn't mess you up. I edited the answer for others who might find this. Thanks for accepting. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
    // Here I register pasport with current user address
    pass = Pasport(msg.sender);
```

Here you treat `msg.sender` as `Password` smart contract, while almost definitely `msg.sender` is not a `Passport` smart contract (I assume this because your `Passport` smart contract is not smart enough to call `vote` function of `Election`).  More over, it is quite probably that `msg.sender` is not a smart contract at all, but rather simple address backed by private key.  Thus here

```
    // Here I check if the user already have pasport
    require(pass.isRegistered(msg.sender));
```

your are trying to call `isRegistered` function on an address that is not `Password` smart contract and most probably not a smart contract at all.

In case `msg.sender` is not a smart contract, this will just return `false` (most probably your case).

In case `msg.sender` is a smart contract, and this smart contract does have `isRegistered(address)` function, this function will be called.  This opens attack vector on your `Eelection` smart contract.  Malicious user may write smart contract that implements function `isRegistered(address)` and returns `true` from it.  Then user may make this smart contract to call `vote` on your `Election` smart contract, and `Election` will permit the vote.

In case `msg.sender` is a smart contract not implementing `isRegistered(address)`, result depends on whether this smart contract implements fallback function, and, if it does, what this fallback function does.  All three results possible: `true`, `false`, or exception.

Now how to fix this.

At first, you should make `pass` to be a state variable, rather than local variable:

```
contract Election
{
    Passport private pass;
```

Then, in the constructor of `Election` you need to accept `Passport` smart contract as an argument and save it in state variable:

```
constructor(Passport _pass, string memory _electionName) public
{
    pass = _pass;
    owner = msg.sender;
    electionName = _electionName;
}
```

Now, in your `vote` method you may safely call `isRegistered`:

```
function vote(uint _voteIndex) public
{
    // Here I check if the user already have pasport
    require(pass.isRegistered(msg.sender));
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Now I understand more clearly what was the main problem — I should have sent not a user address but the address of Passport contract. And thank you for showing the attack vulnerable place, I am still learning so dint thought that this could be done :) Unfortunately right now I can't upvote you because of the account limitation. Have a good day.